# Array between Rails and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a ROR application and i need to get an array from my database and use it on JS , so i did this

```
var tab = <%= @users.collect{|item| item.names }%>;
```

But when i try to use may Tab i get this error :

```
SyntaxError: syntax error   
var tab = [&quot;123456789&quot;, &quot;fDF125847&quot;, &quot;124578&q
```

i think that I need to cast the **& quot; to "** but i dont know how ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JSON for this. Something among the lines

```
var tab = <%= @users.collect{|item| item.names }.to_json %>;
```

Or in case your collection doesn't have `to_json` method, you could use `ActiveSupport::JSON` and its `encode` method.

**UPD**. Also I'd recommend to read [How to Securely Bootstrap JSON in a Rails View](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/04/30/how-to-securely-bootstrap-json-in-a-rails-view/)

Comment: one more details I use Hstor on my database :

Comment: her is the code :
<%= @users.collect{|item| item.details['name'] }

Comment: did you try to apply `.to_json` to it? you show unchanged code from your initial question

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
var tab = <%= @users.collect{|item| item.names }%>;
```

you should write

```
var tab = <%= @users.collect{|item| item.names }.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tab = <%= @users.collect{|item| item.names }.to_s.html_safe %>;
```